# How to disable commenting by % symbol?

Tags: comments

This is the code (I'm trying to create verbatim-ish environment that saves everything to a file):

```
\documentclass{article}
\NewDocumentEnvironment{foo}{b}{%
  \newwrite\myfile
  \immediate\openout\myfile=myfile.txt
  \immediate\write\myfile{\detokenize{#1}}
  \immediate\closeout\myfile
}{}
\AddToHook{env/foo/before}{\obeylines\obeyspaces}
\begin{document}
\begin{foo}
First \LaTeX
% Second
Third
\end{foo}
\end{document}
```

I'm expecting this content in `myfile.txt`:

```
First \LaTeX
% Second
Third
```

However, I'm getting:

```
^^MFirst \LaTeX ^^MThird^^M
```

How to fix both the comment symbol and `^^M` (I expect normal EOL to be there)? Also, the space after `\LaTeX` must not be there.

Comment: as has been commented before you could use `verbatim`  or parts of verbatim.  `\@makeother\%` would work, (I showed how to write a newline in your last question.)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle can you please post a full example? I will gladly accept it!

Comment: I'm more inclined to close as a duplicate of your last question, but ...

Comment: You never get exactly the same output from input using standard catcode settings and `\detokenize`. For example `\a1` is detokenized as `\a 1`. What we have to do is illustrated in OpTeX trick 0091 http://petr.olsak.net/optex/optex-tricks.html#createfile

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the same as your last question

```
\documentclass{article}
\newwrite\myfile
\NewDocumentEnvironment{foo}{b}{%
% no  \newwrite\myfile
  \immediate\openout\myfile=myfile.txt
  \immediate\write\myfile{\detokenize{#1}}%
  \immediate\closeout\myfile
}{}
\AddToHook{env/foo/before}{%
\newlinechar=\endlinechar% as before
\catcode`\%=12\relax
\obeylines\obeyspaces}
\begin{document}
\begin{foo}
First \LaTeX
% Second
Third
\end{foo}
\end{document}
```